# Mysql Connection Pools in Java

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

Are there Third Pary libraries that offer Mysql connection pools in Java?

If yes: What are their advantages and disadvantages?

If no: Are there any guidelines and tutorials for implementing your own Mysql connection pool?

Comment: Off-topic. But of course. [Here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP). Have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have do some work with java and use connection pool.I use a thrid party jar C3P0 which is easily to use.C3P0 has already implements the datasouces interface in java.And you say you are using mysql,you also need a mysql-connecter jar which implements all the interface in java package sql.
  You can find c3p0 here.http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/ and find mysql-connecter at https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/.After you get the two jar,you just need copy them under the lib folder.Then use the class and method the provide.